# The thread 'std::vector<foo *,std::allocator<foo *> >::_Insert_n' (0xf4) has exited with code 0 (0x0)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, stl

When closing my application, I got this strange line in the debug output.

```
The thread 'std::vector<foo *,std::allocator<foo *> >::_Insert_n' (0xf4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I'm used to seeing messages like ...

```
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1ad0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

... or ...

```
The thread 'RPC Callback Thread' (0x1f28) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

... but this is a first. What is this oddly named thread?

Was it started by STL somehow?

**Edit**

---

This is an excerpt of the debug output.

```
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x149c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1b68) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'std::vector<foo *,std::allocator<foo *> >::_Insert_n' (0xf4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1ad0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'RPC Callback Thread' (0x1f28) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Is it just two output messages getting interleaved?

Comment: No, it is not that. It's among several lines of debug messages.

Comment: I've seen console messages get interleaved if they occur on different threads. However looking at it again it appears that the thread name has got corrupted somehow

Comment: I pasted an excerpt of the debug output.